# PCA for RGB image in python

Tags: python, rgb, pca

I'm trying to reduce dimension of RGB images using PCA on python. But it seems to me that all codes I found only work on a greyscale image. Is there any way to do PCA on RGB image using any python library like sklearn or opencv?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PCA of RGB Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533392/pca-of-rgb-image)

Comment: I think that just won't work because you are now throw off channels of color in the RGB image. For example, if you choose the component equals 2, which means now the image only has two channels. @Arman

Answer (score 0):

Separate three channels i.e., Red, Blue, Green and apply PCA on each. After applying PCA on each channel again join them.